# InDesign: Text Won't Justify Center Vertically

Tags: adobe-indesign

I've tried going to text frame options in this preset template and it won't let me change it to center for vertical justification. How do I fix it?

Comment: Do you need help for text frame vertical centering in general? Or do you know how to do it, but are having problems with one specific text frame?

Comment: Ensure you don't have a text wrap on some other item causing the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to either click with the cursor within the textbox or select it with your Selection Tool (<kbd>V</kbd>) prior. Use <kbd>Command</kbd> + <kbd>B</kbd> on a mac to activate the text frame options:

[image]

Vertical alignment options are also available in the top menu bar as three horizontal line icons.

[image]

Since you mention it is a template you are working on, one other cause of not being able to edit the text box could be that it is locked as a master page element. You may need to change the text box on the master page itself, not within the document pages. 
[image]

You can also unlock the element on a document page if the master item is set up to allow overrides by holding <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> when you click on the element, or <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> to unlock all master page elements

Comment: +1 for suggesting to open up Text Frame Options as a troubleshooting step. Helped me clearly identify my issue.